# mingw (msys2) - error: '_stat64' is not a type

Tags: c++, mingw, msys2

Пытаюсь скомпилировать qBittorrent и получаю ошибку:

```
compiling base/bittorrent/nativesessionextension.cpp
In file included from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_file_service.ipp:24,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/asio/detail/win_iocp_file_service.hpp:277,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/asio/basic_file.hpp:37,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/asio.hpp:28,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/libtorrent/ssl.hpp:47,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/libtorrent/tracker_manager.hpp:69,
                 from C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/libtorrent/alert_types.hpp:68,
                 from base/bittorrent/nativesessionextension.cpp:31:
C:/Development/msys64/mingw64/include/libtorrent/alert_types.hpp:1814:27: error: '_stat64' is not a type
 1814 |                         , stat const& s);
      |                           ^~~~
```

Полная строка с ошибкой в alert_types.hpp:

```
TORRENT_UNEXPORT stats_alert(aux::stack_allocator& alloc, torrent_handle const& h, int interval
    , stat const& s);
```

Т.к. ошибка возникает в файле пакета mingw - libtorrent-rasterbar не могу понять, как её пофиксить.
Насколько я понял stat это класс, описанный в include/libtorrent/stat.hpp.
Почему требуется _stat64, которая вроде как структура, описанная в include/_mingw_stat64.h, и почему не является типом мне непонятно.

Comment: Видимо где-то есть `#define stat _stat64`.

Comment: В том то и дело - я "пробежался" поиском _stat64 по исходникам и ничего кроме вышеописанного не нашел. Я не очень хорошо знаком mingw, больше MS VS. Потому и не могу понять, почему возникает такая ошибка конкретно в данном случае. И как выявить её причину и исправить.

Comment: Он в стандартных хедерах, а не в этом коде. Лежит в `/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sys/stat.h:279`.

Comment: Как чинить? Попробовать заменить в коде qBittorrent `stat` на другое слово (а стандартные хедеры не трогать). Если получится собрать, то зарепортить баг в qBittorrent (если у них в документации про это ничего не написано).

Comment: Хм, ну я так и предполагал попробовать. Только вот проблема не в сырцах qBittorrent, а пакете libtorrent, как видно из лога ошибки. Хотя он тоже и сырцов с гитхаба собирается.

Comment: В общем, чтобы не править все упоминания stat исходниках libtorrent, пришлось прописать в include/libtorrent/alert_types.hpp перед строкой, в которой возникает ошибка "#define stat libtorrent::stat", а после неё соответственно "#define stat _stat64".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за подсказку, где искать объявление    #define stat _stat64.